Derivative of Dickman –de Bruijn function at $1$
The Dickman–de Bruijn function $\rho(u)$
is a continuous function that satisfies
$$
u\rho′(u)+\rho(u−1)=0
$$
with initial conditions
$\rho(u)=1$
for $0 \leq  u \leq  1$.
I know that $\rho$ is differentiable for $u > 1$. I was wondering if
if the derivative of $\rho$ from the right at $1$ is bounded or not.
I have not been able to find a reference for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Since $\rho$ is constant on the interval $[0,1]$, you have $\rho'(1^-) = 0$.

Try to plug in $u=1^-$ into the delay equation. It would be interesting to know $\rho’(1^+)$ too.

sorry, it meant from the right. typo fixed

You can compute the left and right derivatives of Dickman's function yourself quite straightforwardly. On one hand, since $\rho$ is constant on the interval $[0,1]$, you have $\rho'(1^−) = 0$. On the other hand, its derivative satisfies $\rho'(u) = -\frac{\rho(u-1)}{u}$ $\forall u > 1$, hence $\rho(1^+) = -\rho(0) = -1$.

Don’t you mean $-1$?

@TymaGaidash. You're right, thanks for spotting the typo, now corrected.
